# Get missing rows in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, function, aggregation

I have a dataframe like this:

```
Object Period
A 202101
A 202102
A 202103
A 202105
A 202107
B 202102
B 202103
B 202104
B 202106
```

Now I would like for each object to iterate and get the missing period between the min and the max of the object, and get something like:

```
Object MissingValues
A 202104 / 202106
B 202105
```

To make the problem easier the object min is minimum 202101 and object max is maximum 202108.

I am a bit lost on how I can do it.
Can you help me?
Thanks

Comment: Please provide sample data as text not images.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the `Period` strings to Pandas period by [`dt.to_period()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html).  Then group by `Object` and aggregate to get the missing periods for each group of `Object`.  Finally, convert the list of missing periods to the desired layout, as follows:

```
df['Period'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Period'], format='%Y%m').dt.to_period('M')

df_out = df.groupby('Object')['Period'].agg(lambda x: sorted(list(set(pd.period_range(x.min(), x.max()).tolist()) - set(x))))

df_out = df_out.apply(lambda x: ' / '.join(map(str, x))).str.replace('-', '').reset_index()
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_out)

  Object           Period
0      A  202104 / 202106
1      B           202105
```

### Edit

If you want the final layout of `Period` as a list of string e.g. ['202104','202106'] instead of '202104' / '202106', you can use:

```
df['Period'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Period'], format='%Y%m').dt.to_period('M')

df_out = df.groupby('Object')['Period'].agg(lambda x: sorted(list(set(pd.period_range(x.min(), x.max()).tolist()) - set(x))))

df_out = df_out.apply(lambda x: [str(y).replace('-', '') for y in x]).reset_index()
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_out)

  Object            Period
0      A  [202104, 202106]
1      B          [202105]
```

Comment: This is better had handling date ranges that span across years.  I perfer this solution.

Comment: @ScottBoston  Thanks!  Your solution is also good!  :-)

Comment: Thanks very much Scott. Finally, I should better put it in a list ['202104','202106'] instead of '202104' / '202106'. Do you know what I should do differently?  I tried this but doesn't work: def f(x):
    listi = []
    x = x.astype(int)
    s = pd.Series(np.arange(x.min(), x.max()+1))
    r = s[~s.isin(x)]
    return listi.append(r.astype(str))

Comment: @ImFabien75  See my edit above for setting it in a list ['202104','202106'] instead of '202104' / '202106'.   Scott prefers my solution and had already deleted his solution.

Comment: Thanks @SeaBean. I get an error thought: TypeError: Passing PeriodDtype data is invalid. Use `data.to_timestamp()` instead I suppose the period conversion is not working :/

Comment: @ImFabien75   Feel free to let me know if you require any further clarification.  :-)

Comment: @SeaBean I need yes :) Didn't you see my last comment? I get an error: TypeError: Passing PeriodDtype data is invalid. Use data.to_timestamp() instead

Comment: @ImFabien75  Oh, I missed your last comment.  Let me look at it now.

Comment: @ImFabien75  Is that you are testing my edited solution ?  Which line of code (out of the 3 lines) that you got the error ?

Comment: @SeaBean I know...It is already a period['M']. then I don't need the first row. But I still have an error :/ at the second row: ValueError: Must produce aggregated value

Comment: @ImFabien75   I see.  Probably you ran the first line of code twice and got that TypeError.  For the  ValueError: Must produce aggregated value   I'm still stimulating the error at my machine.  However, I still can't reproduce the error case at my machine.  I suspect there is some special data input that you run different from the sample data here.

Comment: @ImFabien75  Have you tried using the sample data alone to test the codes ?  Is it ok ?  If yes, how is your whole set of data different from the sample data here ?

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Object':['A', 'A','A', 'A','A','B','B','B','B'],
        'Period':[202101,202102,202103,202105,202107,202102,202103,202104,202106]}
outputDf = pd.DataFrame(data)
uniqueObject=outputDf.Object.unique()
grouped = outputDf.groupby('Object')
outputDf = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Object', 'Period'])

for object in uniqueObject:
    periodValues=[]
    for periodValue in grouped.get_group(object)['Period']:
        periodValues.append(periodValue)
    mini=min(periodValues)
    maxi=max(periodValues)
    periodStr=""
    for i in range(mini,maxi+1):
        if i not in  periodValues:
            periodStr+=str(i)+' / '
    periodStr = periodStr[:-2]
    outputDf = outputDf.append({'Object' : object, 'Period' : periodStr}, 
                ignore_index = True)
print(outputDf.to_string(index=False))
```